# is that possible currying and callback for write and read file?

Tags: javascript, json, api, asynchronous, callback

have you tried to currying some data with callback as well? it such as async, read and write data, 
anyone can give me an example for reading and write file/data by currying and callback ??

is this called by currying and callback ??

```
function curriedReadFile(path, encoding) {
  var done, err, result;
  var cb = function(e, r) { done = true; err = e, result = r; };
  fs.readFile(path, encoding, function(e, r) { cb(e, r); });
  return function(_) { if (done) _(err, result); else cb = _; };
}
```

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying): currying is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument. That doesn't seem to be what you're doing here.

Comment: can u give me example for get and patch data by currying

Comment: What is the purpose of using currying for the procedure?

Comment: is that not possible then to get and patch data by currying ? lets say i want to get 2 kinds of api , and then callback inside them and then call back to patch the data , is that possible

Comment: Currying has nothing to do with the data, it's just about a style of calling functions. Instead of `result = add(a, b)` you write `result = adder(a)(b)`.

Comment: read this https://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/currying-the-callback-or-the-essence-of-futures/

Comment: I see, the trick here is `cb = _` at the end. That overwrites the `cb = function(e, r)` that's assigned earlier. This is then called by the closure that's passed to `fs.readFile()`. The `if` seems to be part of a general template that allows it to work with both sync and async functions.

Comment: can i use that cb again to write file / patch data ??